# ¿Porque no funciona la herramienta sweetalert2 en mi componente vue para cambiar estado a un registro?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, sweetalert2

¡Buenas noches!; tengo en mi componente vue (Categoria.vue) implementado dos funciones que se llaman "desactivarCategoria() y activarCategoria()"; la idea es que al dar un click en el botón desactivar que esta en el dibujo que adjunto del botón con el candado de color rojo cambie del estado a la catgoría, para ellos uso la herramienta de mensajes personalizajes que se llaman sweetalert2 que su pagina oficial es:

[Sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#download)

y para la instalación de esta herramienta de sweetaalert2, de las opciones que aparecen en la parte izquierda seleccione "instalation / instalar" en la parte de arriba escogi jsdeliver CDN instalaller que me abrío una nueva ventana: (con un nuevo link)

[jsdelivr.com/package/npm/sweetalert2](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/sweetalert2)

en donde en la opción npm CDN File en la primera opción abri el archivo y di guardar como una vez al guardar guarda el archivo en la ruta de mi proyecto laravel /resources/plantilla/js/sweetalert2.all.min.js; y en el archivo webpack.mix.js de mi proyecto hice referencia del archivo para cuando lo compile con npm run dev, y luego con php artisan serve haga referencia a la herramienta sweetalert2, lo que adjunto el código del archivo "webpack.mix.js"

```html
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.styles([
    'resources/plantilla/css/font-awesome.min.css',
    'resources/plantilla/css/simple-line-icons.min.css',
    'resources/plantilla/css/style.css'
], 'public/css/plantilla.css')
.scripts([
    'resources/plantilla/js/jquery.min.js',
    'resources/plantilla/js/popper.min.js',
    'resources/plantilla/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'resources/plantilla/js/Chart.min.js',
    'resources/plantilla/js/pace.min.js',
    'resources/plantilla/js/template.js',
    'resources/plantilla/js/sweetalet2.all.min.js'
], 'public/js/plantilla.js')
.js(['resources/js/app.js'],'public/js/app.js');
```

Ahora el código completo de mi componente Categoría.vue (en donde se esta las funciones desactivarcategoria() y activarCategoria() es el siguiente:

```html
<template>
  <main class="main">
      <!-- Breadcrumb -->
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
          <li class="breadcrumb-item active"><a href="/">BACKEND - SISTEMA DE COMPRAS - VENTAS</a></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <!-- Ejemplo de tabla Listado -->
          <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">

                 <h2>Listado de Categorías</h2><br/>

                  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" @click="abrirModal('categoria','registrar')">
                      <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Agregar Categoría
                  </button>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="input-group">
                              <select class="form-control col-md-3">
                                <option value="nombre">Categoría</option>
                                <option value="descripcion">Descripción</option>
                              </select>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar texto">
                              <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Buscar</button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
                      <thead>
                          <tr class="bg-primary">

                              <th>Categoría</th>
                              <th>Descripción</th>
                              <th>Estado</th>
                              <th>Editar</th>
                              <th>Cambiar Estado</th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>

                          <tr v-for="categoria in arrayCategoria" :key="categoria.id">

                              <td v-text="categoria.nombre"></td>
                              <td v-text="categoria.descripcion"></td>

                              <td>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" v-if="categoria.condicion">

                                    <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i> Activo
                                  </button>


                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" v-else>

                                      <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i> Desactivado
                                  </button>

                              </td>

                              <td>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" @click="abrirModal('categoria','actualizar',categoria)">

                                    <i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x"></i> Editar
                                  </button> &nbsp;
                              </td>

                              <td>

                                  <template v-if="categoria.condicion">           

                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="desactivarCategoria(categoria.id)">
                                          <i class="fa fa-lock fa-2x"></i> Desactivar
                                      </button>

                                  </template>
                                  <template v-else>           

                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" @click="activarCategoria(categoria.id)">
                                          <i class="fa fa-lock fa-2x"></i> Activar
                                      </button>

                                  </template>

                              </td>
                          </tr>

                      </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <nav>
                      <ul class="pagination">
                          <li class="page-item">
                              <a class="page-link" href="#">Anterior</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="page-item active">
                              <a class="page-link" href="#">1</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="page-item">
                              <a class="page-link" href="#">2</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="page-item">
                              <a class="page-link" href="#">3</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="page-item">
                              <a class="page-link" href="#">4</a>
                          </li>

                          <li class="page-item">
                              <a class="page-link" href="#">Siguiente</a>
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                  </nav>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Fin ejemplo de tabla Listado -->
      </div>
      <!--Inicio del modal agregar/actualizar-->
      <div class="modal fade" :class="{'mostrar':modal}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-primary modal-lg" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                      <h4 class="modal-title" v-text="tituloModal"></h4>
                      <button type="button" @click="cerrarModal()" class="close" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                      </button>
                  </div>

                  <div class="modal-body">

                      <div v-show="errorCategoria" class="form-group row div-error">

                          <div class="text-center text-error">

                              <div v-for="error in errorMostrarMsjCategoria" :key="error" v-text="error"></div>

                          </div>

                      </div>


                      <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
                          <div class="form-group row">
                              <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="text-input">Categoría</label>
                              <div class="col-md-9">
                                  <input type="text" v-model="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de categoría">

                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group row">
                              <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="email-input">Descripción</label>
                              <div class="col-md-9">
                                  <input type="email" v-model="descripcion" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese descripcion">
                              </div>
                          </div>


                      </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" @click="cerrarModal()" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i> Cerrar</button>
                      <button type="button" @click="registrarCategoria()" v-if="tipoAccion==1" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-save fa-2x"></i> Guardar</button>
                      <button type="button" @click="actualizarCategoria()" v-if="tipoAccion==2" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-save fa-2x"></i> Actualizar</button>

                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.modal-content -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div>
      <!--Fin del modal-->


  </main>
</template>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<script type="module">
   
    export default {
        data(){

            return {

                categoria_id:0,  
                nombre:'',
                descripcion:'',
                arrayCategoria:[],
                modal:0,
                tituloModal:'',
                tipoAccion:0,
                errorCategoria:0,
                Swal:'',
                errorMostrarMsjCategoria:[]
            }

        },

        methods:{

           listarCategoria(){

               let me=this;

               axios.get('http://localhost/proyectolaravel/public/categoria').then(function (response) {
                    // handle success
                    //console.log(response);
                    me.arrayCategoria=response.data;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    // handle error
                    console.log(error);
                });
           },

           registrarCategoria(){

               if(this.validarCategoria()){

                   return;
               }

               let me=this;

               axios.post('http://localhost/proyectolaravel/public/categoria/registrar',{
                 
                 'nombre':this.nombre,
                 'descripcion':this.descripcion


               }).then(function (response) {
                    // handle success
                    //console.log(response);
                    me.cerrarModal();
                    me.listarCategoria();

                }).catch(function (error) {
                    // handle error
                    console.log(error);
                });

           },

           actualizarCategoria(){

               if(this.validarCategoria()){

                   return;
               }

               let me=this;

               axios.put('http://localhost/proyectolaravel/public/categoria/actualizar',{
                 
                 'nombre':this.nombre,
                 'descripcion':this.descripcion,
                 'id':this.categoria_id,
           

               }).then(function (response) {
                    // handle success
                    //console.log(response);
                    me.cerrarModal();
                    me.listarCategoria();

                }).catch(function (error) {
                    // handle error
                    console.log(error);
                });



           },

           desactivarCategoria(id){

                
                const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
                customClass: {
                    confirmButton: 'btn btn-success',
                    cancelButton: 'btn btn-danger'
                },
                buttonsStyling: false,
                })

                swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
                title: '¿Estas tu seguro de desactivar la categoria?',
                text: "No estás habilitado para reversar esto!",
                type: 'precausación',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i> Aceptar',
                cancelButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i> Cancelar',
                reverseButtons: true
                }).then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {

                        let me=this;

                        axios.put('http://localhost/proyectolaravel/public/categoria/desactivar',{
                            
                            'id':id
                    

                        }).then(function (response) {
                                // handle success
                                //console.log(response);
                                me.listarCategoria();

                                 swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
                                'Desactivado!',
                                'El registro ha sido desactivado con éxito.',
                                'satisfactoriamente');

                            }).catch(function (error) {
                                // handle error
                                console.log(error);
                            });
                        


                   
                } else if (
                    // Read more about handling dismissals
                    result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
                ) {
                    swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
                    'Cancelled',
                    'Your imaginary file is safe :)',
                    'error',
                    )
                }
                });



           },

           activarCategoria(id){

               
               const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
                customClass: {
                    confirmButton: 'btn btn-success',
                    cancelButton: 'btn btn-danger'
                },
                buttonsStyling: false,
                })

                swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
                title: '¿Estas tu seguro de activar la categoria?',
                text: "No estás habilitado para reversar esto!",
                type: 'precausación',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i> Aceptar',
                cancelButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i> Cancelar',
                reverseButtons: true
                }).then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {

                        let me=this;

                        axios.put('http://localhost/proyectolaravel/public/categoria/activar',{
                            
                            'id':id
                    

                        }).then(function (response) {
                                // handle success
                                //console.log(response);
                                me.listarCategoria();

                                 swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
                                'Desactivado!',
                                'El registro ha sido desactivado con éxito.',
                                'satisfactoriamente');

                            }).catch(function (error) {
                                // handle error
                                console.log(error);
                            });
                        


                   
                } else if (
                    // Read more about handling dismissals
                    result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
                ) {
                    swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
                    'Cancelled',
                    'Your imaginary file is safe :)',
                    'error',
                    )
                }
                });



           },
           
            validarCategoria(){

                 this.errorCategoria=0;
                 this.errorMostrarMsjCategoria=[];

                 if(!this.nombre)  this.errorMostrarMsjCategoria.push("(*)El nombre de la categoria no puede estar vacio");

                 if(this.errorMostrarMsjCategoria.length) this.errorCategoria=1;
             
                 return this.errorCategoria;
            },

           cerrarModal(){

               this.modal=0;
               this.tituloModal="";
               this.nombre="";
               this.descripcion="";

           },

           abrirModal(modelo,accion,data=[]){
                 
                 switch(modelo){

                    case "categoria":
                    
                    {

                        switch(accion){

                            case "registrar":

                                {
                                   
                                   this.modal=1;
                                   this.tituloModal="Registrar Categoria";
                                   this.nombre="";
                                   this.descripcion="";
                                   this.tipoAccion=1;
                                   

                                
                                }

                                case "actualizar":

                                {
                                    this.modal=1;
                                    this.tituloModal="Editar Categoria";
                                    this.tipoAccion=2;
                                    this.categoria_id=data["id"];
                                    this.nombre=data["nombre"];
                                    this.descripcion=data["descripcion"];
                                    




                                
                                }
                        
                        }


                    }

                }

                        
           }
        
        },
        
        mounted() {
            //console.log('Component mounted.')
            this.listarCategoria();
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
           
     .modal-content{

      width:100% !important;
      position:absolute !important;
  }

  .mostrar{

      display:list-item !important;
      opacity:1 !important;
      position:absolute !important;
      background-color:#3c29297a !important;
  }

   .div-error{

      display:flex;
      justify-content:center;
  }

  .text-error{
      
      color:red !important;
      font-weight:bold;
      font-size:20px;
  }

</style>
```

pero al momento de ejecutar mi proyecto laravel me ejecuta correctamente, me muestra los registros, los puedo editar, guardar, pero al cambiar estado no se ejecuta y da un error, adjunto pantalla:

[image: Categoria.vue - listado de registros]

[image: Categoría.vue -Error al cambiar de estado]

me gustaría saber ¿como soluciono este problema que tengo en la ventana de la herramienta sweetalert2 que no muestra antes de cambiar a cambiar el estado del registro de categoría?; su ayuda.

Para el usuo de la herramiento Swetalert2 seguí los pasos que me indicaron en la página [sweet alert 2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)

para la realización del ejercicio de la ventana use como ejemplo la opción que esta en el link:

[Sweet Alert 2 /Ejemplo](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples)

La que dice: "... and by passing a parameter, you can execute something else for "Cancel"."; este es el código:

```html
const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
  customClass: {
    confirmButton: 'btn btn-success',
    cancelButton: 'btn btn-danger'
  },
  buttonsStyling: false,
})

swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
  cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
  reverseButtons: true
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
      'Deleted!',
      'Your file has been deleted.',
      'success'
    )
  } else if (
    // Read more about handling dismissals
    result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
  ) {
    swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
      'Cancelled',
      'Your imaginary file is safe :)',
      'error'
    )
  }
})
```

(Código de ejemplo) pero que indica que variable Swal no ha sido definida.

Comment: Por favor pon tu error como texto, y muestra solo las partes del codigo relevante.

Comment: Estimado @gbianchi hice una captura de pantalla del error que me sale al realizar inspeccionar lo que practicamente me sale el error "swal not found variable"; que ese el error que me sale que variable swal no encuentra ahora bien en mi componente "categoria.vue" dentro de methods: que esta las funciones desactivarCategoria() y activarCategoria() alli esta uso de la herramienta sweetalert2. Si puedes me ayudas de esta herramienta.

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre. Las imagenes no se pueden indexar y son muy dificiles de ver.

Comment: No tengo ni idea como funciona eso para vue. Tene en cuenta que a VUE le importa poco y nada laravel. Tu pregunta es sobre vue y el uso de ese sweetalert que ni se que hace. Buscate si ese componente tiene una version para vue?

Comment: Estimado @gbiachi sobre esta consulta ¿algún otro usuario en esta páginas que conozcas que me pueda ayudar?; espero no molestarte.

Comment: Jose, las preguntas son abiertas. Todos los usuarios las ven. Lo que si te pido, es que centralices la pregunta en el problema esencial. Errores como texto, el codigo para reproducir el error, sacar todo lo que sea ruido o informacion que no aporta. Creo que tus preguntas tienen ese problema y por eso no reciben la atencion que merecen. Miraste [ask]?

Comment: @gbianchi ¿de que ruido hablas?; estoy detallando deteninamente lo que quiero hacer y comparto el código de mi componente vue para que sepa un usuario de donde llama a las funciones desactivarCategoria() y activarCategoria() ya que tambien uso la herranienta sweetalert2 no veo que estoy ofendiendo de ninguna manera a nadie estoy detallando el inconveniente

Comment: mira por favor [mcve]. y pon el error como texto porfa...

Comment: y es preferible que siempre en vue uses los componentes propios de vue (por ejemplo encontre este: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sweetalert2)

Comment: SweetAlert crea un objeto global para usar sus funcionalidades. Del mismo modo que JQuery suele usar `$`, en este caso tienes que usar `swal`, con **todas las letras en minúscula**

Comment: La pregunta, aunque es buena, me parece excesivamente detallada. Date cuenta que si al hacer una pregunta presentas taaaaanto código vas a echar para atrás muchas posibles respuestas que habrían surgido si el código fuese más reducido. Este tipo de preguntas conllevan bastante tiempo de lectura para tratar de ayudar al que la hace, por lo que muchas suelen acabar sin respuesta. Te recomiendo que cuando tengas un problema trates de encapsularlo, poniendo solamente las partes implicadas de código.

Comment: Estimado @PabloLozano, ¡Buenas tardes!; para realizar la códificación de la ventana elegante con sweetalert2 realice de acuerdo al siguiente página del sweetalert2 https://sweetalert2.github.io/ y de esta página una vez instalado este herramienta escogí como ejemplo con el título que dice: "... and by passing a parameter, you can execute something else for "Cancel".; de lo que me sale un error de variable Swal no ha sido definido tal como esta en la captura de pantalla de arriba.

Comment: @JoseFernandoFrugoneJaramill cambianste Swal por swal? te dijo que el objeto se llama en minuscula pablo. Probaste ese cambio?